# Node.js server on localhost upload files to live server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, file, express

So I have an app that can post images etc within its own structure. I can post my backbone models(JSON data) to a live mongodb server with mongoose, something like this `mongoose.connect(configDB.url);` and all my messages in the app even from localhost are sent to a live server.

I am not sure how I can post images/files to a live server? I am using node.js with express as a server and also using these handy plugins https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload with the middleware https://github.com/aguidrevitch/jquery-file-upload-middleware.

I can post images to the local site directory like this

```
upload.configure({
    uploadDir: __dirname + '/public/img',
    uploadUrl: '/img',
    imageVersions: {
        thumbnail: {
            width: 80,
            height: 80
        }
    }
});
```

That is cool when my app is live, but I have several computers in the office running node locally and want to test the file upload, I just need the images to be hosted, similarly to what amazonS3 can do.

I hope I can learn something here. Thanks everyone who takes the time!

Comment: I havent used PHP in a while but I remember doing something like this was relatively easy. There has to be a way to connect to my `var/www/` folder, maybe I should purchase amazonS3 and have them host video/images for me, a CDN would be cool!

Comment: You want a static file serving middleware.

Comment: Ok I am going to look into that now thanks... would that middleware work with this middleware https://github.com/aguidrevitch/jquery-file-upload-middleware or take it's place?

Comment: I was going to use the nginx upload module that seemed promising for this but I couldnt get it installed for the life of me. Actually destroyed my server trying to install that puppy :(

Comment: I really want to achieve this so I can work on my app in localhost but I may have to just host the thing live.

Comment: I think I may have to look into CORS https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Cross-domain-uploads

Comment: No; you simply need something like https://github.com/isaacs/st.

Comment: Wait I'm confused, isn't what I am doing now storing static files? I am sorry if I am lost but how does this POST my image onto my cloud server from localhost?

Comment: Then what is your problem? Why do you need a cloud server?

Comment: Well just for development. I have several machines running my app in localhost with socket.io. It's a messaging app, my messages are being stored on a live mongodb server and I can send messages to all the machines in realtime but I am not sure how I can upload the images to the server so I can view them on all the machines. Obviously as of now the images are being stored on the machines disk so I get an empty message with no image.

Comment: You could store them in a network share or database, then serve them from every server.

Comment: Yeah I store the messages in the database but I didnt know I can store images in a database.. and good idea with network share! I just implemented that throughout all the machines and can share files easily I could do that... I stopped doing that with project files because task runners(gulp) would take to long to compile on the network so I used github to share my files but looks like I can use network share again!

Comment: You can store the images only on a network share, not the source.